# Character of Exterior Product of Standard Representation

Tags: representation-theory

Letting $V=U\oplus W$, where $U$ is the trivial representation of $S_n$ and $W$ is the standard representation of $S_n$, I want to find the inner product $\langle \chi_{\wedge^k V}, \chi_{{\wedge^k V}}\rangle$.  I know it's supposed to be equal to 2, but I am having trouble showing it.

So far, I used the fact that ${\wedge^k V}=(U\otimes {\wedge^{k-1} W})\oplus {\wedge^k W}$, and then expanding $\langle \chi_{\wedge^k V}, \chi_{{\wedge^k V}}\rangle$, we find that $\langle \chi_{\wedge^k V}, \chi_{{\wedge^k V}}\rangle=\langle \chi_{\wedge^k W}, \chi_{{\wedge^k W}}\rangle+2\langle \chi_{\wedge^k W}, \chi_{{\wedge^{k-1} W}}\rangle+\langle \chi_{\wedge^{k-1} W}, \chi_{{\wedge^{k-1} W}}\rangle$, so it all boils down to knowing the characteristic of the $k^{th}$ exterior product of the standard representation.

I am not sure if this is the right direction to go.  If so, any ideas on how to proceed would be very helpful. If not, some hints as to what would be the right direction would be great. Please do not use the fact that the exterior product of the standard representation is irreducible, since that's what I eventually hope to prove using the result of the inner product. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V$ is the permutation representation coming from the action of $S_n$ on $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$. Show that $\wedge^k(V)$ is the permutation representation coming from the induced action of $S_n$ on $k$-element subsets of $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$. You can compute the inner product between permutation representations using Burnside's lemma.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I can see what you mean by working through an example, but I am still having trouble piecing it all together for the general case. Could you please provide some more details?

Comment: I'm also not entirely clear on how to use Burnside's Lemma for the inner product. I know that we can get $\chi_{std}(\sigma)= \# \left\{ \mbox{fixed points of } \sigma \right\} -1$ from Burnside's Lemma, but I'm not sure how to use that for the character of the exterior product. Thanks!